# Can anyone explain why the use of が not を in this sentence その建物から町全体が見下ろせる

Tags: japanese-to-english

I'm currently learning Japanse, but then I stumbled upon a sentence in a [dictionary](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E8%A6%8B%E4%B8%8B%E3%82%8D%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B)
その建物から町全体が見下ろせる which has the meaning:
*"The building looks down on the whole town"*

But I'm confused, isn't が a subject marker particle? Shouldn't を have been used instead, which is an object marker particle?

Comment: Did you translate the sentence, or was the translation provided?

Comment: it's written in the dictionary as an example sentence, including the translation.

Comment: 見下ろせる is potential form of 見下ろす. Which particles go with potential?

Comment: Also, which word did you look up and in what dictionary?

Comment: Related: [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/43676)

Comment: The sentence is from Tanaka Corpus, not the dictionary. Tanaka Corpus is a collection of translations from various languages, they aren't created by that website for the purpose of demonstrating that usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse that sentence like this:

> その建物から
> From that building
>
> 町全体が見下ろせる
> the entire town is overlook-able.
> the entire town can be overlooked.

So yes, 町全体 is indeed the subject of the sentence.

In general, potential form in Japanese work slightly different from English potential expressions. Try reading `～が[verb](ら)れる` as "X is [verb]-able" or "X can be [verb]ed" rather than "I can [verb] X".

Still, it's also fine to say その建物から町全体**を**見下ろせる. For details, please read the following questions.

- [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/5010)
- [Why is it 日本語がわかります instead of 日本語をわかります?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2505/5010)
- [The に particle and potential form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13323/5010)