# What's the difference between 信じる, 信用する and 信頼する?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, verbs

What's the difference between 信じる, 信用する and 信頼する ? How can I know which one to use? According to my dictionary they all mean "to trust". Are they interchangeable?

For example,

> I trust you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Off the top of my head I would summarize the differences as follows.

- 信じる is to believe a single fact or statement (or, by extension, believe that something exists or is true)
- 信用する is to have faith in a source of information
- 信頼する is to trust a person (or institution)

So, for example

> 田中さんを信じる。
> I believe what Mr. Tanaka said.
>
> 田中さんを信用できる。
> I can ["always"] believe what Mr. Tanaka says.
>
> 田中さんを信頼する。
> I trust Mr. Tanaka [to always do the right thing].

Comment: Another way to interpret the last statement, 信頼 also carries the nuance of reliance. I can trust (rely/count on) Mr. Tanaka. This comes from the second kanji in the compound: 頼{たよ}る, 頼{たの}もしい

Comment: 「彼女を信用できる」じゃなくて、「彼女が信用できる」です。

Comment: ^ ＠Dmytro, 「彼女**を**信用できる」「彼女**が**信用できる」... どちらもOKです。Both sound fine. 　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/9831

Answer (score 1):

I understand that 信用 implies trustworthiness based on the past, whereas 信頼 implies confidence or reliance on some person/thing for the future.