# 息がつく（つける） and 息をつく（つける） difference?

Tags: grammar, particle-が, particle-を, transitivity

I'm used to seeing 息をつく and it's easy to understand in parallel to English, as を marks the object (to take => a breath).

However, I saw this sentence in a dictionary:

> 彼の情熱的な抱擁で彼女は息がつけなかった。
> His passionate embrace took her breath away.
>
> (出典：プログレッシブ和英中辞典)

**Why is 息 marked here as the object (assuming が is used here as an object marker)? Would rewriting the sentence as**

> 彼の情熱的な抱擁で彼女は息をつけなかった。
> His passionate embrace took her breath away.

**make any difference?**

Answer (score 1):

> が is used here as an object marker

That's right.

> make any difference?

No difference (or minor difference) I think.

---

呼吸をするという意味の「息を吐く(いき を つく)」 という表現は、多くの人が、知らないと答えると思います。(漢字で書けば、意味は通じます。)

多くの人は、「息を吐く」と書くと、「いき　を　はく」　と読むと思います。

---

呼吸をするという意味で、多く使われる表現は、「息」-「を」-「する」です。

「息-を-する-こと-が-できる/できない」を省略した表現が、
「息-が-できる/できない」　です。

「息-を-できる/できない」でも、意味は通じます。

ただ、省略する場合は、「を-する-こと」を省略するので、
「息-が-できる/できない」の方が正しいと思います。

---

「息がつけない」は、「息がつけない展開」などの、特定の表現で使います。

「息がつけない展開」の「息がつけない」は、「緊張する」あるいは「どきどきする」という意味です。

この「息がつけない」が、「緊張する」あるいは「どきどきする」という意味になるのは、
「息がつけない」=「息をつく」ことができない = (気持ちを)ひと休みさせることができない = 緊張する　ということだと思います。

---

「息がつける」は、あまり見かけません。たまに見かけるのは、「息がつける場所」などの表現です。
これは、「安心できる場所」という意味だと思います。

「息がつける」= not「息がつけない」= not「緊張する」= 「安心する」　ということだと思います。

息(呼吸)ができる場所 = 安全、安心な場所 = 安心して休める場所　という意味もあると思います。

---

息がつく　は、使いません。

「息をつく」　は、「ひと休みする」という意味で使う、フレーズです。

「息をつく」には、「息を吐きだす」という意味もありますが、多くの人が、そのような意味があることを知らなかったと答えると思います。

「ひと休みする」という意味で使う場合は、「一息(ひといき)つく」あるいは、「一息いれる」という表現の方が多いです。

---

「息がつけない」は、多くの場合「息もつけない」のことだと思います。

「息もつけないほど 忙(いそが)しい」という表現で使います。

「息つく暇(ひま)もない」などの表現も使います。

息もつける　は、使いません。

---

「息をつく」normally means "have a break"

「息もつけない」means "too busy"

「息をつく暇もない」also means "too busy (to have a break)"

---

links to Japanese - Japanese dictionary (from デジタル大辞泉)

[息を吐く(いき を つく)](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%81%AF%E3%82%92%E5%90%90%E3%81%8F-431115)

links to Japanese - Japanese dictionary (from weblio)

[息をつく](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%81%AF%E3%82%92%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F)

[息をつく暇もない](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%81%AF%E3%82%92%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F%E6%9A%87%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

[息もつけない](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%81%AF%E3%82%82%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

Comment: 「つける」という可能形を使っているために、「が」になったのでは？例：「目を離す」→「目**が**離**せ**ない」「英語を話す」→「英語**が**話**せる** 」、なので「息をつく」→「息がつけない」

Comment: 辞書を探してみたのですが、「が」を使う例がみつからなかったので。
「つける」という可能形を使っているために「が」になった、というのは、日本語の感覚としては正しいと思います。

Comment: @choco 是非解答欄にてお願いします。直感ですが、質問者さんは、「つく」の他動詞形としての「つける」と、可能形としての「つける」を混同されているようにも思われます。

Comment: @choco 「息をすることができる」（省略して「息をできる」あるいは「息ができる」）という表現もできますので、可能形だから「が」になる　というのは、必ずしも正しいとは限りません。本来の「息をする」という表現のかわりに「息をつく」が使えるように見えた、ということだと思います。また、「息がつける」はあまり使わず、「息がつけない展開」などの特定の表現で使う場合が多いと思います。

Comment: @l'électeur 「息を吐く(つく)」の場合の「つく」は、他動詞でよいと思います。(偶然かもしれませんが、) 他動詞と解釈した点では、質問者が正しいと思います。

Comment: 『可能形だから**必ず** 「が」になる』と言ったのではありません。『この辞書の例文を書いた人は、可能形だから「を」を「が」にしたのでしょう』という意味です。

Comment: l'électeurさんはそういうことを言っているのではありません。l'électeurさんは、『この辞書の例文「彼女は息がつけなかった」の「つける」は、他動詞‌​「つく（吐く）」の可能形「つける」であるのに、質問者は‌​、自動詞「つく」の他動詞・使役(causative)動詞形の「つける」(「蝋燭に火をつける」「ウッドデッキに屋根を付ける」‌​「おまけに朝ご飯も付ける！」などの）だと勘違いしているのではないか』と言っているのです。

Answer (score 0):

> 彼の情熱的な抱擁で彼女は息がつけなかった。
>   Why is 息 marked here as the object (assuming が is used here as an object marker)?

It's because of the potential form つける. The つける(吐ける) is the potential(可能形) form of the transitive verb つく(吐く).

For example:
「英語**を**話す」--> 「英語を話せる」「英語**が**話せる」「英語**が**話せない」
「目**を**離す」--> 「目を離せない」「目**が**離せない」
「単位**を**取る」--> 「単位を取れない」「単位**が**取れる」「単位**が**取れない」
「論文**を**書く」-->　「論文を書けない」「論文**が**書ける」「論文**が**書けない」
を can be replaced by が when using the potential form. [This thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/609/the-difference-between-%E3%81%8C-and-%E3%82%92-with-the-potential-form-of-a-verb) might be of some help.

Likewise,
「息**を**つく」(take a breath) -->「息をつけない」「息**が**つけない」(can't take a breath)

> Would rewriting the sentence as
>   彼の情熱的な抱擁で彼女は息をつけなかった。
>   make any difference?

I don't think it would make much difference. I think some people would prefer が over を especially in a negative sentence (though it would depend on the context).