# Is the "ga" in 「○○○が食べたい」 standard japanese?

Tags: particle-が, particle-を

The [Langfocus](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNhX3WQEkraW3VHPyup8jkQ/videos) youtube channel came out with a new [video](https://youtu.be/x9-e_3GHrzw?t=880) on Japanese. In it he explains that the が can be used to express focus. I have never heard (probably not paid attention) or learnt this. So, my question is: is this standard Japanese, or rather colloquial use?

`ドーナッツが食べたい` instead of `ドーナッツを食べたい`
to express focus on "donut"

Comment: See: [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/542)

Comment: Well, about the duplicate mark: the question _is_ different, but the answer on the linked page does indeed match this question as well.