# 生徒が分かる and 彼が見える and Intransitivity

Tags: particle-が, particle-を, potential-form, transitivity

I have been searching all internet and haven't found an "acceptable" answer for it yet. I hope you guys can help me!

I was reading a text in the website KawaJapa about 分かる and the sentence 日本語が分かる. As a matter of fact, わかる is 自動詞 and means something like "understandable" and not "to understand" which is transitive, so "Japanese is understandable/comprehensible to me (私には)".

Following this line of thought, 見える would be the same: 富士山が見える, "Fuji-san is visible". However, I was watching one lesson in Youtube from the channel Nihongonomori about the uses of ために・ように and he gave two sentences that confused me:

> 1. 生徒**が**分かるように、ゆっくり話します。
> 2. 彼**が**見えるように、手を振る。

I understand the meaning of both sentences, but if I analyze it based on what was taught in Kawa Japa's website, then it doesn't make sense to me because both sentences would sound like:

> "The students are understandable" **and** "he is visible"

When I know the sentences actually mean:

> 1. "so the students will understand..." and
> 2. "so he sees (me)..."

Shouldn't the sentences be, for example:

> 1. （テキストが）生徒**に**分かるように、ゆっくり話します。
> 2. （私が）彼**に**見えるように、手を振る。

So which sentence is more appropriate?
Nihongonomori's

> 1. 生徒**が**分かるように、ゆっくり話します。
> 2. 彼**が**見えるように、手を振る。

or mine:

> 1. （テキストが）生徒**に**分かるように、ゆっくり話します。
> 2. （私が）彼**に**見えるように、手を振る。

I hope I could express my doubt in a clear way. Sorry for the big text.

みんな、教えてください。

Comment: `彼が見えるように` <-- 確かに・・「He is visible」って思っちゃいますよね・・

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Are you suggesting that 彼が見えるように、手を振る sounds wrong, or just that 彼が見えるように sounds like "He is visible" when read out of context?

Comment: @Chocolate Maybe I misunderstood. I understood your comment to mean that when you hear 彼が見えるように you think of "he is invisible", but the OP says the translation should be "so he sees (me)", so I got confused.

Comment: @user3856370 The latter, I guess... （ごめんね、コメント書きなおそうと思って消しちゃった）You're right, I meant when I hear/see 彼が見えるように I'd interpret it as "he's visible" (when there's no context)... to clearly say "so that he can see me" and avoid any confusion I'd probably say 彼に見えるように.

Answer (score 2):

生徒**に**分かるようにゆっくり話す and 生徒**が**分かるようにゆっくり話す are interchangeable. In short, `X + が + potential-form` can both mean "X can do" and "one can do X; X is doable". (Consider わかる as a kind of potential verb.) You have to infer the correct interpretation from the context.

Unsurprisingly, when X is an animate object the sentence tends to mean "X can do", whereas when X is an inanimate object the sentence tends to mean "X is doable". It's usually not difficult to determine the correct meaning in one way.

> - このキノコは食べられます。 This mushroom is edible.
> - 彼は食べられます。  He can eat (it). (<sup>[?]</sup>He is edible.)
> - 星が見えます。 I can see stars.

Some sentences can be ambiguous if there were no context at all:

> - 彼は殺せます。 (Someone) can kill him. / He can kill (someone).
> - 彼が見えます。 I can see him. / He can see it (e.g., the stage).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. 生徒が分かるように、ゆっくり話します。

- **日本語が分かる**。
- 生徒が**日本語が分かる**ように、私はゆっくり話します。
- 生徒が**日本語のテキストが分かる**ように、私はゆっくり読{よ}みます。
- 生徒が**日本語のテキストが理解できる**ように、私はゆっくり読｛よ｝みます。

> 2. 彼が見えるように、手を振る。

- **富士山が見える**。
- 彼が**富士山が見える**ように、私は彼を高台{たかだい}に案内｛あんない｝します。
- 彼が**私が見える**ように、私は手を振る。
- 彼が**私に気づく**ように、私は手を振る。