# Why is this sentence using が here?

Tags: particles, potential-form

> 娘が一人で服が着られるようになった。

着る is supposed to take を but it's using が here. Why?

Comment: Hint: 着られる is the potential form of 着る.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/609/the-difference-between-%E3%81%8C-and-%E3%82%92-with-the-potential-form-of-a-verb and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60066/is-there-a-good-etymological-reason-why-the-potential-form-in-japanese-requires