# Direct object marked with a が?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-が, particle-を, adverbs

I found the next sentence:

> 懐かしい。目を閉じれば、彼女との昔の事がまざまざと思い出せる

It's marked with a が because of the adverb? Or is it something else?

Comment: It's because of the potentiality of the verb 思い出せる. FYI: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/43676

Comment: Potential verbs describe a quality of something.  Depending on intention and emphasis, these may take を or が.  Amanda S's explanation at the link provided by @aguijonazo is a good one, make sure to read that.

Comment: To put it another way, when you have a potential verb and the noun is marked with が, the potential verb is being used to describe something about the noun -- the potential verb is used as a verb describing a state, syntactically a bit like an adjective, and since we're talking about the noun's quality, the noun is the subject and is marked with が.