# What is the difference between が（suru-verb）できる and を（suru-verb）できる?

Tags: grammar, particles

For example, what's the difference between the following sentences?

> ゲームで勝つことで、ポイントを獲得できる。
> ゲームで勝つことで、ポイントが獲得できる。

Intuitively, I felt like the first sentence sounded better and [example sentences](https://yourei.jp/%E7%8D%B2%E5%BE%97%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B) seem to back that up. What's the difference between using を and が with a する verb (in potential form)? If both are alright, and when does one sound more natural than the other?

I have seen [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/609/the-difference-between-%E3%81%8C-and-%E3%82%92-with-the-potential-form-of-a-verb) as well, does the same thing apply here?

Comment: When I read the question in the list, I was initially baffled as to what you meant.  Your question title is a bit confusing -- what you indicate by （名詞【めいし】） is not just any noun, but specifically a noun that functions as a する verb.  Replace 獲得【かくとく】 with 鶏【にわとり】 or 飛行機【ひこうき】 or 果物【くだもの】, or any other non-する-verb noun, and all you've got is gibberish.  **Suggestion:** Reword the question title slightly to clarify that this is for する-verb nouns.

Comment: I feel this is similar (but not exactly the same) to "score a point" vs "score the point".

Comment: The difference is very subtle, but I think you have already found the right existing question...