# Which particle to use for potentials

Tags: grammar, particles, potential-form

So i notice は、が、を are used in this case.
For example:

英語**が**話せます

英語**を**話せます

英語**は**話せます

*I know my example might be wrong but im a beginner and absolutely clueless on this subject  *

So how do we decide which one to use. Does it depend on the verb or the meaning we try to imply?

Comment: For が and を, see [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609).  For は, the general difference between は and が applies; [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22) might help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/609/the-difference-between-%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%82%92-with-the-potential-form-of-a-verb)

Answer (score 0):

Personally speaking, I don't sense much difference between が and を but I think there's a slight difference with は to those. は has a nuance of limiting targets and the limited one is 英語 in your scenario. Basically, it's like saying:

> 英語は話せます (が、フランス語は話せません)

And a listener might expect a next topic (which is that you can't speak French).