# Meaning of 旅がしたい vs 旅をする

Tags: particles

In *Spice & Wolf* [trailer](https://youtu.be/0AjvWnTn50k), as far as I can understand Holo says わっちは主【ぬし】と旅がしたい; I'm trying to understand why が and not を, since one would usually say (I think) 旅をする, and 旅 is the object of したい.

I found some grammar pages (like [this](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/tai-form/)) using を, and [this question](https://ja.hinative.com/questions/1842283) on HiNative where an user says with が is more natural, while another that they are almost the same.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find that question; it could answer my question, if my understanding is right: in that sentence I could use を, but が is right (not sure which one is more natural), and since in the past it was the only correct choice it could be that Holo uses that because she has an antiquate way of speaking; could this be right?

Comment: Both are perfectly correct, and I personally do not feel that one sounds "older" than the other. But I do feel the same difference as explained [in this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/5010); it's hard for me to explain logically, but 旅 feels a little more "focused" with が.

Comment: I kinda get it, don't worry; I think those answers answer mine too, thanks.